# xPath: Select one of multiple Following elements, if it exists (OR)

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

Using xPath for Selenium, I want to look for an element that follows a conditional parent node. However, I want it to look for *multiple* possible following nodes.

Is there a way to select the element following the conditional node, as either `span` or `p`, ***if*** one of them are present?

```
try:
    elmnt = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                        ("//*[text()[contains(., 'myConditionString')]]" + 
                                        "/following::span or following::p") #← Find this 
                                        ).text
except:
    pass
else:
    print elmnt
```

The xPath should be looking for both:

```
<root>
    <b>myConditionString</b>
        <span>Find me!</span>
</root>
```

and this at the same time:

```
<root>
    <b>myConditionString</b>

    <p>Find me!</p>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you provide an `HTML` sample code and specify the target element you want to `find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following `XPath` and let me know if it still not correct:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//b[text()="myConditionString"]/span[text()="Find me!"] | //b[text()="myConditionString"]/p[text()="Find me!"]')
```

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//b[text()="myConditionString"]/span | p[text()="Find me!"]'` should also be valid.

Comment: See this thread for shortening long OR conditions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910443/how-to-shorten-long-xpath-expressions-with-many-or-alternatives/37911265#37911265