# How to shorten long XPath expressions with many OR alternatives?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am working to get Selenium to go through a large number of alternative conditional XPaths, looking for elements that *may match* – and pass that on to the object `elmnt`.

Currently, using the `OR` operator (`|`), the code quickly gets very repetitive and exhaustive, especially when there are a lot of possible variations.

In the example below, the only variation is that I start looking for `h1`, `h2`, or `h3`. The rest is the same.

```
for word in ["testString1", "testString2", "testString3"]:

    try:
        elmnt = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                            (
                                                "//h1[text()[contains(., '%s')]]" % word + 
                                                "/following::p" + 
                                                "|" + 
                                                "//h1[text()[contains(., '%s')]]" % word + 
                                                "/following::span" +

                                                "|" +

                                                "//h2[text()[contains(., '%s')]]" % word + 
                                                "/following::p" + 
                                                "|" + 
                                                "//h2[text()[contains(., '%s')]]" % word + 
                                                "/following::span" +

                                                "|" +

                                                "//h3[text()[contains(., '%s')]]" % word + 
                                                "/following::p" + 
                                                "|" + 
                                                "//h3[text()[contains(., '%s')]]" % word + 
                                                "/following::span"
                                            )
                                            ).text
    except:
        pass
    else:
        print elmnt
        break
```

But in my actual code, I will be looking at even more variations, including various node types in `/following::` besides `p` and `span`.

**Question:** Is there some way to simplify (shorten) this?

My first hope was that it'd be possible to do something like:

```
"//[h1|h2|h3][text()[contains(., '%s')]]" % word
```

i.e. that the `or` operators could be "baked into" the XPath expression without having to use fully exhaustive string concatenations like in the example. And if so, that idea could've been applied across the board.

However, this does not seem to be possible.

Is the solution to create some sort of generative function that creates the entire xPath string, or something else?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but this would answer at least partially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this shortened XPath (leveraging the `self::` axis as recommended by [@alecxe in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910443/xpath-is-it-possible-to-shorten-long-expressions-with-many-or-alternatives/37911265#comment63272915_37910443)):

```
  "//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3][contains(., '%s')]" % word
+ "/following::*[self::p or self::span]"
```

Note that this tests that the *string value* of `h1`, or `h2`, or `h3` contains the value of the `word` variable (rather than the string value of the immediate text nodes).  Also, if you want to actually test that the string value of those elements *are* rather than *contains* `word`, use `[.='%s']` instead.